# events inside jQuery Modal

Tags: jquery, events, modal-dialog

In my modal window I try to map the select change event and execute a method on select value with the following code

```
$(document).bind('show.oc.popup', function(e) {
    alert() //this works on each call
    self = this
    self.$popupContainer = $(e.relatedTarget)
    self.$popupForm = self.$popupContainer.find('form')

    self.$id = $( "input[name='file_id']" ).val()

    $('select[name=type]', self.$popupContainer ).change(function(){
        alert('') // this never getting called
        self.loadTypeInfo(false, true)
    })

});
```

but on change I never get an alert

**My Markup**

```
<select name="type" data-field="" data-request="" class="form-control custom-select select2-offscreen" title="" tabindex="-1">
        <option value="">URL</option>
        <option value="">CMS Page</option>
        <option value="">Blog category</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does `'show.oc.popup'` event fire and if so are `this` and `e.relatedTarget` what you expect them to be? Not sure why you need to bind change handler inside another event in the first place, can't you just delegate it?

Comment: thank you for your feedback I will try delegate as well

Comment: A few observations. (1) You don't have semi-colons at the end of your javascript statements. In js, every statement (line) must end with a ` ; ` Temporarily remove everything except the `alert()` statement -- get that working first. Then add each line back in, line by line (or as much as possible). (2) Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` - unless you are using a very old version of jQuery.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', 'select[name="type"]', function(e) { //code });`

Comment: thank you for your advices I just started to use october cms which comes with own ajax framework and I try to extend with my own prototype. Actually `on` works in this case but select event won't get mapped